# rig with automatic weights to visible bones only

Tags: rigging

I have an object and a rig with many bones. Now i wanna use "parent with automatic weights", but just to some bones.

I hoped i could do that with selecting bones in pose mode, hide them and then press a to select the visible bones and that then the parenting would only be done to the visible bones. Unfortunately Blender parents it still to all bones.

Is there a way to tell Blender only to use the visible bones somehow? or what is the "normal" workflow for that? Or do i have to select "manually" my bones which i want to parent? (but i would love to use my excluding method...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the armature, shift select the mesh, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, select the bones you want with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> then header menu > *Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones*:

[image]

Comment: i made a small video about my "very first" problem before your solution :( ....i couldn't select any bones. You can check it here: https://youtu.be/36wO-yTFURs Also i want to say that i don't want to manually select the bones i want to parent to, but i wanna exclude bones by hiding (or something else). Is this possible?

Comment: You first need to parent: Ctrl P > Armature Deform. Yes if you make the bones invisible in Pose mode and use the method I told you, they won't create any weight

Comment: aaaah....you didn't write that. Always consider me as beginner ;)